# How to connect multiple digital sensors with single wire?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, sensor, arduino-uno, pir

I am new to Arduino, and I have a problem that I can't solve on my own.
I am trying to connect multiple [PIR](https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/HC%20SR501%20PIR%20Sensor%20Datasheet.pdf) motion sensors with a single wire, in parallel and onto one pin on my Arduino.

I am thinking of putting a different resistor on every sensor so when motion is detected and electricity goes through the sensor, the Arduino can detect how much voltage has come to Arduino. I don't know, this is the only solution I could come up with.

Comment: it would be better if you can post the type of PIR

Comment: Do you need to identify which one is set of, and if so, even when more than one is set off at the same time? Or only know that at least one of them has been set off?

Comment: PIR sensors usually have a N/C switch. If you connect them in series, with a different resistor across each switch, you can construct a ladder network whose resistance will show which sensor has become open circuit.

Comment: Hi, I am working with hc-sr501 motion sensors. I would like to know exactly which one has detected motion and also if more of them have been set on at the same time.

Comment: Why one wire only?

Comment: @Vid I'm seeing the datasheet say "TTL output: 3.3, 0" (which isn't TTL.) I also see a series resistor going to the output pin. Is this what you also see? Or did I get the wrong datasheet?

Comment: Vid, why not [edit] your question and include the PIR part number and link to the datasheet? Don't bury essential information in the comments.

Comment: Why don't you start with your definition of "multiple"? 2? 10? 1000?

Answer (score 2):

Make a DAC converter with the outputs (through the 1k internal resistor).

The bit of the binary value of voltage is directly related to the PIR which has detected something.

EDIT: R1 should be 2*RR.

[image]